# Set filename of an only streamed zip file

Tags: java, stream, zip, filenames

i am currently creating a zip file and filling it with various json files and images. All this should only run in memory and not on the hard disk. Therefore I have the following construct so far:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zip = null;
String FILE_NAME = "file.zip";

try {
   zip = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
   //now the critical part where the name of the file should be set
   ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(FILE_NAME);
   zip.putNextEntry(entry);
   byte[] data = FILE_NAME.getBytes();
   zip.write(data, 0, data.length);
   zip.closeEntry();
   //end of critical part and filling the rest of the zip
   //...
   //
}finally{
   IOUtils.closeQuietly(zip);
   byte[] byteFile = baos.toByteArray();
   IOUtils.closeQuietly(baos);}
```

The problem is that the zip-file is called file.zip, but also contains a file.zip itself.
How can I name my Zip file from the ZipOutputStream without packing into this one file with the same name? Unfortunately I only found this solution here.

Comment: Since you're keeping the ZIP "file" in memory it doesn't have an inherent name. I'm also not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the "file.zip" entry. What are you doing with the bytes afterwards? Knowing your intentions may help with providing a solution.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess there was some information missing. The byte[] is used for a new InputStream which in turn is used in a HTTP response to offer the file for download.

Comment: In that case, you can communicate the intended file name via the `Content-Disposition` header.

Answer (score 0):

```
public byte[] zipBytesFile(List<byte[]> files) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);

    int i = 0;
    for (byte[] file : files) {
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(++i + ".pdf");
        entry.setSize(file.length);
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);
        zos.write(file);
    }

    zos.closeEntry();
    zos.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```